How to draw a rotating cube on a 2D canvas in C# without using external libraries?
I need to draw a 3D-like cube on a 2D canvas in C# (using Graphics in Windows Forms) and make it rotate around its axes. However, I am not allowed to use any external libraries like OpenGL or DirectX that handle this for me. How can I manually implement 3D rotation and projection onto a 2D canvas? Any resources or guidance on working with rotation matrices and perspective projection in C# would be appreciated!
At this stage I have only managed to draw a cube using primitives.
graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, width / 2 - x, height / 2 - x, width / 2 + x, height / 2 - x);
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, width / 2 - x, height / 2 - x, width / 2 - x, height / 2 + x);
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, width / 2 + x, height / 2 - x, width / 2 + x, height / 2 + x);
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, width / 2 - x, height / 2 + x, width / 2 + x, height / 2 + x);

            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, width / 2 + x, height / 2 - x, width / 2 + x + 3 / 2 * x, height / 2 - x - 3 / 2 * x);
            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, width / 2 - x, height / 2 - x, width / 2 - x + 3 / 2 * x, height / 2 - x - 3 / 2 * x);

            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, width / 2 - x + 3 / 2 * x, height / 2 - x - 3 / 2 * x, width / 2 + 2 * x, height / 2 - x - 3 / 2 * x);

            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, width / 2 + x, height / 2 + x, width / 2 + 2 * x, height / 2 + x - 3 / 2 * x);

            graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Brown, width / 2 + 2 * x, height / 2 + x - 3 / 2 * x, width / 2 + 2 * x, height / 2 + x - 3 / 2 * x - 2 * x);


Not a lot of info here. Is the goal to implement a full renderer with shading? Textures? Just a wire frame? Can you pre-render to an animation? Embed a WPF control with 3D capabilities?

First, we need to get the 8 points of our cube and be able to rotate them. Quaternion math is really complicated, but the API's for them are pretty easy once you get the hang of it.
This is the basic gist of how I would do it (and there's probably better ways, I'm not so proficient with graphics). Anyway, you get 4 non-opposing corners of a cube in 3D space. Rotate them in 3D-space, then transform them to their 2D representation. Figure out which of those corners is, in 2D space, closest to the center and remove it. Copy the negative of the remaining points and you end up with 6 points that you can draw as if they were a cube.
This might break for the edge case where your cube is facing to the front, in which case you only need 4 points to draw your cube. But that is left as an exercise for the reader.
public class RotatedCube
{
    public Vector3[] points = new Vector3[4]
    {
        // This combination of points is important here!
        new( 1,  1, 1),
        new( 1, -1, 1),
        new(-1, -1, 1),
        new(-1,  1, 1),
    };

    public Vector2[] GetPoints2D(Quaternion rotation)
    {
        Vector2 points2D = new Vector2[6];
        
        // Rotate the 3D point and make it 2D.
        // Whilst we are doing that, figure out which point is closest to the center.
        double lowestLength = double.MaxValue;
        int lowestIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var point = Vector3.Transform(point[i], rotation);
            points2D[i] = new Vector2(point.X, point.Y);
            var length = points2D[i].LengthSquared();
            if (length < lowestLength)
            {
                lowestLength = length;
                lowestIndex = i;
            }
        }

        // Remove the point closest to the center and copy the reverse of the other points.
        points2D[lowestIndex] = points2D[3];
        points2D[3] = -points2D[0];
        points2D[4] = -points2D[1];
        points2D[5] = -points2D[2];
    }

    public void Draw(Quaternion rotation)
    {
        // This won't work because the graphics API expects an array of Point[]
        // but you get the idea, just times it by 100 or sumethin'
        // Also you're lucky I was bored and have worked with 2D representation
        // of 3D objects before :)
        var points2D = GetPoints2D(rotation);
        graphics.FillPolygon(myBrush, points2D);
    }
}


A better option would be to implement a check for only front facing triangles, and rendering only those. There should be plenty of 3D software rendering tutorials online to help you. I've done exactly this in Win32 using only GDI/GDI+ without DirectX, except for use of the DirectXMath math library which supports SIMD vector and matrix operations. I presume your project will also allow the same, as long as all rendering still takes place in software.
